# PCA9685 servo not working

Tags: arduino-nano, servo, shields

[image]

[image]

I am working on a project where I want to connect 12 servos together.
I got:

- Arduino Nano Every
- PCA9685 16-channel, 12-bit PWM/servo shield
- Power supply 5 V, 10 A

I got a PCA9685 16-channel, 12-bit PWM/servo shield from Adafruit. I connected all the wires as they are supposed to be and I connected the shield to an external power supply, but the servos are not moving.

I don't know where the problem comes from.

I'm using the Adafruit library. It's not even moving one servo (although the servo moves when connected directly to the Arduino).

I have another wire connected to add a button. Here is my wiring diagram:

[image]

I am using code from the original project, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: First, you should solder the connections to the Arduino properly, and check you haven't shorted reset to ground with stray wire strands sticking out.

Comment: Maybe use more flux when soldering, sl that you get nice smooth connections. The green while doesn't look like it is actually connected to the solder pad